# How to use GPGS in a web-libgdx game?

Tags: gwt, libgdx, google-play-games

sorry for my English.

How to use GPGS in a web-libgdx game?

If I understand correctly, I need to use RestAPI and javascript(I do not have enough skills in JS) with GWT in libgdx. But I don`t know how to relate everything.

I have not find examples or articles on this topic so I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`REST API` is an option for this though, but there are various other options to choose from. One of the easiest way is to use the platform specific code via [interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code)

Everything that doesn't get integrated directly with libGDX won't work the "write once, run anywhere" way - this applies for achievements, leaderboards.

So what you do is to add the library dependencies to the projects you generate. Then implement a generic interface, `AchievementHandler` with methods like `unlockAchievement(String achievementId)`. You can then implement this via `AndroidAchievementHandler` which in-turn uses GPGS.

A sample application demonstrating how this can be achieved is available on github [here](https://github.com/julienvillegas/libgdx-GPGS).

Hope this helps!